# How to check if user can download file in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have an application that uses Sharepoint 2013 API and i want to check if current user can download file from sharepoint library. I try to use EffectiveBasePermissions field of the library and its method Has like this:

```
library.EffectiveBasePermissions.Has(PermissionKind.DownloadListItems)
```

But there are no constant like PermissionKind.DownloadListItems! What constant i can use for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer by trial and error methid! I can use PermissionKind.OpenItems